# There are no commands defined in the "DataTables" namespace

Tags: laravel, datatable

I’m trying to implement a datatable into my laravel project, I installed yajra datatables in the project and everything ..

I add these to the `app.php` :

```
YajraDataTablesDataTablesServiceProvider::class,
'DataTables' => YajraDataTablesFacadesDataTables::class,
```

But when i try to make a new datatable using the command

```
php artisan datatables:make Companies
```

I get this error :

> There are no commands defined in the "DataTables" namespace.

Any idea how to solve this !!

Source: Laravel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try  to install the buttons plugin first http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-installation.  Look [here](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1392)

Comment: Also your register provider and facade on your config/app.php file is wrong https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#service-provider--facade-optional-on-laravel-55

Answer (score 0):

For those encountering the same issue:

You need to install the buttons plugin first http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-installation.